# Google Maps Javascript V3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

First of all, apologies for another of such a question but i can't seem to find a similarity between the existing questions and mine, so here I go

my index.html is as follows:

```
<html><script id="employee-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class='header'><a href='#' class="button header-button header-button-left">Back</a><h1>Map</h1></div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%"></div>
    </div>    
</script></html>
```

so this is a part of the index.html which the div houses the map. so the next section is where the above gets 'compiled and called'

=============**EDITED**==============

```
var EmployeeView = function(employee){

    function initMap(){
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
    };

    this.render = function(){
        this.el.html(EmployeeView.template(employee));
        return this;
    };
    this.initialize = function(){
        this.el=$('<div/>');
    };
    this.initialize();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);  
}

EmployeeView.template = Handlebars.compile($("#employee-tpl").html());
```

so with the above logic, somehow i'm still getting the error below :(

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a listener on the window load, because it seems that you try to access to the map before it's rendered, and you get `null` message.

Wrap your initialisation into a function and call it like :

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

---

```
function initMap () {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
}
```

Comment: oh my, that just works! i was calling it wrongy as i was originally calling the method initMap() so as a benefit to others that might need this, i am now calling it like below `this.initialize();
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);`

==apologies i thought it had worked :( but sadly it didn't change anything==

Comment: if i copy and use your code above, it would throw below error `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined `

it is now edited as above

Comment: That's normal, you need to wrap all your map initialisation into a function, called `initialize` or whatever you want :)

Comment: In your case you can replace by `initMap`

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Apercu, however it its now throwing `Uncaught ReferenceError: initMap is not defined` and i am calling it like so: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);`

Comment: Its now throwing another error `ncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'initMap' ` :(

Comment: Replace `initMap` by `initialize`

Comment: if i replace it back to `initialize` it would throw the previous error `Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined ` hmm:(

Comment: Have you replace the two `initMap` ?

Comment: editted mt question above but its now not loading anything just a blank page though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42247/discussion-between-apercu-and-eddy)

Comment: @panky-sharma Avoid editing answer with minor code-style improvements and by adding strange characters that don't belong here.

Comment: @pankysharma Sell? Buggy? Do you even know javascript? There is no condition here.